# Prevent input field lose focus using generic function. jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set the focus to the input field. The actual problem is whenever i press the backspace key the focus on input textbox is lost (because of language translator). But the problem is solved and i am able to set the focus back on the input field. I am new to the jquery, so I don't know how to make the input focus function generic for all input fields. Here i just make a focus for one field.

Here is my try

```
    var keyBspace = false;
    function OnDownKey() {
        $('#txtfield').keypress(function (event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '8') {
                keyBspace = true;
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    }

    function OnblurEvent() {
        $('#txtfield').blur(function (e) {          
            if (keyBspace) {
                var self = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () { self.focus(); }, 5);
            }

        });
    }
```

How to make this function generic for all input fields. Help needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sepecific selector `#txtfield` use generic selector like `input["text"]`:

```
var keyBspace = false;
function OnDownKey() {
    $('input["text"]').keypress(function (event) {
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if (keycode == '8') {
            keyBspace = true;
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
}

function OnblurEvent() {
    $('input["text"]').blur(function (e) {          
        if (keyBspace) {
            var self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () { self.focus(); }, 5);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But this code set focus to all input fields one by one (loop mode) in the forms. I can't able to enter the values in text box, because of its running focus.

Answer (score 0):

For all text fields use `$("input[type='text']")`